# VB Compilation Type Not Defined When In Fact Its In The Same DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, compiler-construction

I'm totally confused by this.  I'm trying to compile a VB project that I've inherited from someone else.  I've got the full source code on my machine from the SVN repository, the project is a VS2008 VB.NET class library project.

Just for brevity to explain the problem I'll use some pseudo code.  The structure of the dll for this example looks like this:

```
MyProject.MyDll
 - MyAbstractClass.vb (Public MustInherit Class MyAbstractClass)
 - MyClass.vb (Public MustInherit Class MyClass Implements System.Collections.IEnumerator)
```

MyClass contains a method like:

```
Public Overridable Function MyMethod(ByVal myAbClass As MyAbstractClass) As MyAbstractClass
```

What possible scenarios could produce the compilation error like `Type 'MyAbstractClass is not defined.` on the MyClass file?

I never touch VB, I'm solely a C# guy but my understanding is that the differences are really more or less syntactic so considering these classes are more or less right next to each other in the project my C# brain is having a hard time working out why this is an issue.

I could understand it a little better if the classes were defined in separate projects and a reference was broken but thats just not the case here.

Comment: Is it in a different namespace?

Comment: No they're in the same name space.

Comment: They are both abstract (MustInherit)

Comment: Can you possibly show the type declarations (including the namespaces)?

Comment: I've updated the question with both the declarations.  I'm utterly stumped on this.  Weirdness ...

Comment: The only issue I can see at the moment is that `MyClass` is a [keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20fy88e0(v=vs.110).aspx) in VB.Net. But if I escape it (`[MyClass]`) or change it to something else, it works fine.

Comment: That's just pseudo code and not reflective of the real class names so that isn't the issue.  Thanks anyway chap.